# Inversion of Control definition

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

In Spring reference we read:

> IoC is also known as dependency injection (DI). It is a process whereby objects define their dependencies, that is, the other objects they work with, only through constructor arguments, arguments to a factory method, or properties that are set on the object instance after it is constructed or returned from a factory method.

Do I understand correctly? dependencies is -

1) other objects they work with, only through constructor arguments, arguments to a factory method

2)properties that are set on the object instance after it is constructed or returned from a factory method

Please give simple examples of these two items and second question - what is the factory method? Explain in detail, please.

Comment: this will give short-form answer https://www.java2novice.com/java_interview_questions/inversion-of-control/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies are, from that definition, the:

> other objects they work with

For example, let's say you have this class:

```
class Widget {
    public void DoSomething() {
        WidgetCalculator calculator = new WidgetCalculator();
        int someValue = calculator.calculate();
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

In this setup, `Widget` has a dependency on `WidgetCalculator`.  It's an object that `Widget` "works with", or rather, an object that `Widget` needs in order to perform its own work.  The code above does the job, but it leads to tight coupling.  You can't easily swap out a different implementation of `WidgetCalculator` for example, breaking changes in one class can break the other class, etc.

This is where [dependency inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) becomes useful.  Instead of *creating* an instance of `WidgetCalculator`, it can *require* one.  This could be as simple as:

```
class Widget {
    public void DoSomething(WidgetCalculator calculator) {
        int someValue = calculator.calculate();
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Now in order to perform the operation, whatever consuming code is invoking that operation needs to provide the `Widget` with its dependency.  If there is a lot of code on `Widget` with that dependency, it could be promoted to a constructor argument so that consuming code can't even *create* a `Widget` without supplying the dependency:

```
class Widget {
    private final WidgetCalculator calculator;

    public Widget(WidgetCalculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        int someValue = this.calculator.calculate();
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

There are various ways in which a dependency can be provided, but the core principle is that the object requires that the dependency be provided to it rather than seek out the dependency itself.